# Selenium HTTP ERROR: 403 Forbidden for Proxy

Tags: selenium, jenkins, phpunit, selenium-grid

I have a selenium hub up and running at `http://server:4440`, and on 2 separate machines I have a node on each registered on the grid, which I can see in `/grid/console`.

When I try and connect to the hub in my `PHPUnit Selenium2` tests, I get a no active session error. Code from test case:

```
public static $browsers = array(
    array(
        'browserName'       => 'firefox',
        'host'              => 'my-jenkins',
        'port'              => 4440
    )
);
```

FWIW, here are the node and hub service startups. 
Hub:

```
java -jar E:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar -role hub -hubConfig E:\\selenium\hub.json
```

Hub config file:

```
{
"host": "my-jenkins",
"port": 4440,
"newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
"servlets" : [],
"prioritizer": null,
"capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
"throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
"nodePolling": 5000,
"cleanUpCycle": 5000,
"timeout": 300000,
"browserTimeout": 0,
"maxSession": 5,
"jettyMaxThreads":-1
}
```

Node:

```
java -jar E:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig E:\selenium\node.json -hub http://my-jenkins:4440/grid/register -DfirefoxProfileTemplate=E:\selenium\firefox_profiles\selenium_tester -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=selenium_tester -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=E:\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe
```

Node config:

```
{
"capabilities":[
{
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "browserName": "firefox",
  "maxInstances": 1,
  "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
},{
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "browserName": "internet explorer",
  "version": "11",
  "maxInstances": 1,
  "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
},{
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "browserName": "internet explorer",
  "version": "10",
  "maxInstances": 1,
  "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
},{
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "browserName": "internet explorer",
  "version": "9",
  "maxInstances": 1,
  "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
}
],
"configuration":{
"maxSession":7,
"port":5556,
"register":true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"nodeTimeout":120,
"nodePolling":2000,
"registerCycle":10000,
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"timeout":30000
}
}
```

When browsing to `http://localhost:5556`, I get a

```
403 Forbidden
Forbidden for Proxy
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. stop your hub and check if other processes use this port.
   For Windows:

Win + R >> run `cmd` >> `netstat -aon | findstr :4440` most right column shows PID of processes that use this port.

or via **Resource Monitor**. Win + R >> run `resmon` >> Network >> Listening ports

2. in your test you should interact with hub. I've worked with `Java` and had:

   WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4440/wd/hub"), capabilities)

http://localhost:5556 - this is a node.

you should interact with your node via hub:
http://localhost:4440

I've tried to directly navigate to a node on my working environment and get the same error.

```
HTTP ERROR: 403

Forbidden for Proxy
RequestURI=/

Powered by Jetty://
```

From [Selenium documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#how-selenium-grid-works-with-a-hub-and-nodes):

**How Selenium-Grid Works–With a Hub and Nodes**

A grid consists of a single hub, and one or more nodes. Both are started using the selenium-server.jar executable.

The hub receives a test to be executed along with information on which browser and ‘platform’ (i.e. WINDOWS, LINUX, etc) where the test should be run. It ‘knows’ the configuration of each node that has been ‘registered’ to the hub. Using this information it selects an available node that has the requested browser-platform combination. Once a node has been selected, Selenium commands initiated by the test are sent to the hub, which passes them to the node assigned to that test. The node runs the browser, and executes the Selenium commands within that browser against the application under test.